# Justify $ f(z)g(z) := \sum\limits_{j=0}^{\infty}\varphi_j z^j$ for $|z|\leq 1$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, laurent-series, holomorphic-functions

Let $\psi_j$ be a sequence of comlex numbers such that $\sum\limits_{j=0}^{\infty}|\psi_j| < \infty$. Then
$$
f(z) = \sum_{j = 0}^{\infty}\psi_jz^j
$$ 
is a holomorphic function on $|z|<1$ since the series converges absolutely. Now let $g(z)$ be a complex polynomial.

I want to understand/justify the following relation:

> $$
> f(z)g(z) = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\varphi_j z^{j} \qquad \text{for} \quad |z|\leq  1.
> $$

My ideas:

1. $f(z)g(z)$ is holomorphic on $|z|<1$ as a product of two holomorphic functions on $|z|<1$. So there exists a Laurent series for the product on the open unit ball $|z|<1$.
2. To justify the above representation for the closed ball $|z| \leq 1$, I think of considering a holomorphic extension of $f(z)g(z)$ which would also be defined in the neighborhood of the unit circle and coincide with $f(z)g(z)$ on $|z| \leq 1$.
3. Or maybe I should consider a holomorphic extension of $f(z)$.

But I am unsure whether it is possible or whether there is a better way to understand/interpret/justify the above equation.

Comment: @Benjamin: Please do *not* add `\displaystyle` to the titles, compare https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730/42969 or https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3135/42969.

Comment: What exactly are you asking for? $f(z)g(z) = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\varphi_j z^{j} \text{for}  |z|\leq  1$ makes no sense if $f$ is only defined *inside* the unit disk. And how can you prove a relation if the $\varphi_j$ on the RHS are not defined at all?

Comment: I do not want to prove anything. I want to give a meaning to this, preferably with Laurent series. As for $f$, I say it is defined via the series for $z \in \mathbb{C}$, so  it is holomorphic  on $|z|<1$.

Comment: No, that power series need not converge for any $z$ with $|z|>1.$